# Whitelabel iOS application

Tags: ios

I would like to build an iOS whitelabel application which should be customizable to a certain extend and then submitted to app store without manual intervention. So I'd like to know whether Apple has API support that lets me talk to iTunes and submit the app on behalf of the user.

I'm looking at a solution similar to AppBreeder where you can publish the app from the web builder and it will end up in appstore after the approval process. I'm not quite sure if they are manually submitting the app to the appstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automatic submission API. You have to use Application Loader or the built-in submission tool in Xcode to submit to the App Store, but you can definitely do it on behalf of a user if they agree for their app to be listed under your company's name. Not sure about the legal issues around this, but it's a technical possibility.

To do it I would suggest getting them to package an unencrypted `.ipa` or `.xarchive` on their end and do a file upload to you, then you can sign it with your own App Store provisioning profile prior to submission.

Answer (score 0):

NO. Apple does not provide any such API to upload application on iTunes. AppBreeder or MobileRodie or any such website manually upload the application on app store.