# Way to perform white labelling of IOS application

Tags: ios, white-labelling

My application is already on apple store, now I want to perform while labeling on that application. How can i do it.I have an idea that by creating different target with different app ID,I can achieve this but want to know the whole process in detail.Is white labeling is allowed by app store? After applying while labeling can I upload my multiple application with different app id?Is app store approve it?

Comment: Please ref below url:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171388/whitelabel-ios-application

Answer (score 0):

No, Apple won't support automatic white labeling of APP thru API.